# ARKit snapshot gives deformed model

Tags: ios, arkit, snapshot

I have ARKit app with animated model. When i take snapshot model gets deformed like in image below. The eyeballs are moved up. And for another animation they completely disappear and sometimes it happens with teeth. 
And there is fixed time in animation, if snapshot taken, this happens. Like Balls are out while it bows down, they disappear while animation is about to end. Other time they are good.

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here? And any solution?

Edit: Code

```
@IBAction func cameraBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    snapImageView.image = sceneView.snapshot()
    saveImageView.isHidden = false
}
@IBAction func saveBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapImageView.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    saveImageView.isHidden = true
}

@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

saveImageView is `UIView` with snapImageView and save button

Comment: How are you taking your screenshot?

Comment: can you share your code, how you have taken snapshot and saved it.

Comment: I'm also having some issues with .snapshot() My problem is more that the blend modes on materials are not working in the snapshot  image, but are rendered find in the AR view.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the deformation comes from your animation file (is it a .dae?) you should carefully look all frames, exporting (conversion) to Xcode may introduce deformations too. I had experienced quite the same thing before, not specifically on taking a snapshot but deformation of an animation while playing. Also try another tool to convert the animation to Xcode.

Comment: Yes it is dae. Do you know of any particular problem while exporting?

Comment: And this happens only when taking snapshot. Other time it runs fine.

Comment: Well I would start looking at the Xcode preview of the animation. I just installed 9.4 beta and not sure how good it is but will try it late today.